# "The agreement was ratified by parliament" - why no definite article?

Tags: articles

A [quote](http://in.reuters.com/article/2014/08/12/serbia-nis-idINL6N0QI3BZ20140812) from Reuters:

> "The agreement was **ratified by parliament**," Borislav Stefanovic, a senior party official, told the Beta news agency.

Why is there no definite article before **parliament**? Is that OK?

Comment: Two things - That's the 'quote' i.e. someone 'said' it and secondly, the speaker is probably Russian! :P In short, should it have been spoken by some native speaker or the sentence was from some reputed daily, it must have had it!

Comment: The quoted official is Serbian, and I guess it is a translation from Serbian. That hardly justifies snubbing articles though. (0:

Comment: Russian does not use articles at all. Serbian is also a Slavic language, and may also not use articles. I'm not familiar with it, so I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I know, Iea, that's the reason articles give me headaches sometimes. (0: But Reuters says the official was speaking to a Serbian news agency. I guess the quote is a translation. I understand why it could've been omitted but still I wonder would it be a mistake to omit the definite article there, purely from the grammar standpoint.

Comment: Most of the speakers (especially non-native) don't bother grammar in their speeches/statements until it conveys the message what they want to convey!

Answer (score 2):

[Google's n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+parliament%2C+by+the+parliament&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20parliament%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20parliament%3B%2Cc0) shows that both uses are possible. However, I would spell them differently:

> 1. The agreement was ratified **by Parliament**.
> 2. The agreement was ratified **by the parliament**.

In 1, [*"Parliament"*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Parliament) is used as a proper noun and hence it doesn't admit the definite article *"the"*. In 2, [*"parliament"*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/parliament) is used as a common noun and hence the definite article *"the"* is necessary to indicate that the speaker expects us to know what parliament they are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the word '[parliament](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/parliament)' requires the definite article *the.* That's because Borislav Stefanovic is talking about a particular parliament that ratified the agreement.

As I said in my comments, why the article isn't there could be due to two reasons. It is, after all, a quote i.e. someone said it in a colloquial style. And secondly, it's spoken by a non-native speaker.

So, grammatically yes, it does require the definite article.